# Validation for radio in knockout js

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have a list radio got from ajax:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: availableServices">
    <div class="row">
         <label>
             <span class="cb"><input type="radio" name="service" data-bind="attr:{value: number}, checked: $root.selectedService"></span>
             <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
             <span data-bind="text: price"></span>€
             <span data-bind="text: duration"></span>min
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to show a error when radio is not checked by validation knockout. 
Can u help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use next binding for it:

```
    <span style="color: red;" data-bind="text: 'Please, select service', 
       visible: !selectedService()">
```

this `span` should be outside of `<div data-bind="foreach`
[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cZA9M/)

Comment: I am using template for error. I will show automatically. I want to add a validation for it to element.eG: service: ko.observable("").extend({required: true})